# Cómo corregir este error de acceso a un ApacheHTTP en un contenedor Docker?

Tags: windows, docker

Cordial saludo, al correr un contenedor docker obtengo este error:

[php7:error] [pid 21] [client 172.21.0.1:55718] script '/var/www/html/index.php' not found or unable to stat

y como consecuencia en la url localhost:8081 obtengo error de forbiden...

> Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server.
> Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) Server at localhost Port 8081

El docker-compose es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muestra la configuración de docker/docker-compose.

Comment: ok, allí está y muchas gracias por lo que puedas ayudarme al respecto.

Comment: Sugerencia: comparte los archivos de configuración, el código y los logs como texto. Le hace más fácil todo a los que intentan ayudar

Comment: Pareciera que `${PROJECT_ROOT}` no este apuntando a una carpeta con `index.php` (por lo tanto no hay `index.php` en el contenedor). SI usas un archivo `.env` para iniciarlo podrias el contenido con las variables relevantes.